# Laravel : Structure and organize routes.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm trying to use `GET|POST|PUT|DELETE` in my controllers.

I feel like my `routes.php` file is going to get messy as my project  bigger and bigger, as I will have to register lots of routes for all the `GET|POST...` requests.

This is the structure I'm using now:

```
<?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Home Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

//Get
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex');
Route::get('/home/logout', 'HomeController@getLogout');

//Post
Route::post('/home/login', 'HomeController@postLogin');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Appointment Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
//Get
Route::get('appointments', 'ApptController@getIndex');
```

Is there a better way to do this? How can I organize/improve this file?

Can you give me some advice? Thanks!

Comment: I think you're looking for RESTful / resourceful controllers: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can route incoming requests directly to your existing `Controller`s using the `Route::controller()` method in `routes.php`:

```
Route::controller('home', 'HomeController');
Route::controller('appointments', 'AppointmentsController');
```

Then all requests to `home/*` will go be handled by your `HomeController`, `appointments/*` will go to `AppointmentsController` etc etc etc.

It looks you have already created your functions in the Controller using the HTTP method, so then:

a `HTTP GET` to `'/'` will be handled by `HomeController@getIndex()`
a `HTTP GET` to `'logout'` will be handled by `HomeController@getLogout()`
a `HTTP POST` to `'login'` will be handled by `HomeController@postLogin()`

More in the excellent and eloquent Laravel docs [here](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers)

Answer (score 2):

There some ways you can improove your routes, in the case above, you can for example do this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'home'), function()
{
    Route::get('logout', 'HomeController@getLogout');
    Route::post('login', 'HomeController@postLogin');
});

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex');
```

Another way to improove you code, is think more restful. This Way you can handles methods like create, delete, index, update in one line of code like so:

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');
```

Take a look at: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers